# LM2576 may I use bigger or lower inductors?

Tags: power-supply, buck

I'm about to build a switching (Buck) power supply with an [LM2576](http://www.ti.com/product/lm2576) adjustable IC. Input voltage 30V, output from +3V up to +28V, which should run about 100 mA - 3 A load.

If I use a bigger or lower inductor will it have a big negative impact? 
I have:

- 22uH 3A
- 100uH 6A
- 220uH 3A
- 330uH 3A
- 470uH 3A

May I use one of these?
Is it OK if I'll use 220uH, 3A?

From the datasheet it looks like I need something like 150uH 3A. 
Should I use a smaller one or must it be exact?

Comment: I strongly recommend you check out TI's Webench. In my experience the LM25xx series of regulators are a bit difficult to work with if you don't understand all the details. Webench will let you play with the design a bit. http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/analog/webench/overview.page?DCMP=analog_power_mr&HQS=webench-pr

Comment: This device has fixed compensation. "Is is OK?" is going to be something you'll need to empirically evaluate over the load and input ranges.

Comment: My experience is that using an inductor an order of magnitude higher or lower than the recommended value (100uH for this one) is guaranteed to fail pretty badly with these chips.

Comment: Respawned Fluff:
You're saing  (100uH for this one), this one I have. Do you think I could use it?
Thank you!


Matt Young:
I'll try this one.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The first-order effect of using a larger inductor (all other things kept equal) is to reduce the ripple current in the inductor by a proportional amount.

In a DCM (discontinuous conduction mode) regulator, this also limits the load current, since that is proportional to the ripple current.

In a CCM (continuous conduction mode) regulator, the static load current is not affected, but the dynamic response of the regulator will be somewhat slower.

The degree to which this particular chip can tolerate this sort of change requires a careful perusal of its datasheet.

Comment: So which available henry range I can have (like: 22uH - 150uH) ? Or must I use exactly 150uH?
I'm not really sure if my calculation are correct and that's why I asking.
Thank you!

Comment: Basically other part of my question was if I can use one of these for this situation:

22uH 3A; 
100uH 6A; 
220uH 3A; 
330uH 3A; 
470uH 3A; 


Input 30V DCfrom transformer, 
Output adjastable 3-28V posetive, 
load 100mA - 3A.

Answer (score 0):

got it working with 33uH 47uH and 220uH without -major- problems apparently
the logic inside the chip adapts but here's the take. current response from the inductor at switching time wouldn't be much appropiate for some applicates it will sort of ringing spikes the more current is required and applied. apparently this is solved by using only the recomended inductors which are a specific winding and copper materials for the smoothest 3A. if you add inductor from other measurements try to find out the one with the most clear and bright conductor and the smoothest toroid ferrite it will have way less ringing and you could use it with some high end loads nearing 2A at most. that's my take.